# Counting Sort odd results for list with duplicate entries

Tags: c, sorting

I am using counting sort to sort a selection of numbers read from a file. This appears to work fine for files without duplicate entries, but once there are duplicates lots of zeros start to appear.

Do you have any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Examples:

Input (without duplicates):

> 1612 1894 3018 4212 6046 12894 13379 14408 14615 16394 17982 23004
>   27588 31393 33195 39526 54326 54566 67926 72479 90466 157832 703908

Output:

> 0: 1612 1: 1894 2: 3018 3: 4212 4: 6046 5: 12894 6: 13379 7: 14408 8:
>   14615 9: 16394 10: 17982 11: 23004 12: 27588 13: 31393 14: 33195 15:
>   39526 16: 54326 17: 54566 18: 67926 19: 72479 20: 90466 21: 157832 22:
>   703908

Input (with duplicates):

> 1612 1894 3018 4212 6046 12894 13379 14408 14615 16394 17982 23004
>   27588 31393 33195 39526 54326 54566 60000 60000 60000 60000 703908

Output (see 18++):

> 0: 1612 1: 1894 2: 3018 3: 4212 4: 6046 5: 12894 6: 13379 7: 14408 8:
>   14615 9: 16394 10: 17982 11: 23004 12: 27588 13: 31393 14: 33195 15:
>   39526 16: 54326 17: 54566 18: **0** 19: **0** 20: **0** 21: 60000 22: 60000

Input:

> 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3

Output:

> 0: **119** 1: **110** 2: **2025792** 3: **3249376** 4: **56** 5: 2 6: 2 7: 2 8: 2 9: 2

Snippet of code being used to produce this output:

```
int *numbers = (int *) calloc(rows, sizeof(int));

int i = 0;
int max = -1; //min
int min = 500000000; //max
while(fscanf(inputPtr, "%d", &numbers[i]) != EOF) {
  //printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
  if(numbers[i]>max) max = (int) numbers[i];
  if(numbers[i]<min) min = (int) numbers[i];
  i++;
}

countingSort(numbers, rows, max, min);

void countingSort(int array[], const int end, const int max, const int min) {
  int i;
  const int range = max-min+1;
  int count[range+1],
      scratch[end];

  for(i=0; i<range+1; i++)
    count[i] = 0;

  /* Set the value of count[i] to the number of
   * elements in array with value i+min-1. */
  for(i=0; i<end; i++) {
    int c = array[i]-1-min;
    count[c]++;
  }

  /* Update count[i] to be the number of
   * elements with value less than i+min. */
  for(i=1; i<range; i++)
    count[i] += count[i-1];

  /* Copy the elements of array into scratch in
   * stable sorted order. */
  for(i=(end-1); i>=0; i--) {
    int c = array[i]-min;
    int s = count[c];
    scratch[s] = array[i];
    /* Increment count so that the next element
     * with the same value as the current element
     * is placed into its own position in scratch. */
    count[c]++;
  }

  for(i=0; i<end; i++)
    array[i] = scratch[i];
}
```

---

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // FILE stderr fopen fclose fprintf printf fgets
#include <stdlib.h> // Standard Lib :-)
#include <math.h> // Every body was kung fu math

/**
 * Given any number of program parameters (command-line parameters)
 * calculates the length of each one, and writes the longest to standard output
 * this time using counting sort!
 */

/*
 * Output the usage
 */ 
void usage () {
  printf("Usage:\n"
         "Usage: part2 rows fileToRead\n");
}

/**
 * counting sort
 * http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Counting_sort
 */
void countingSort(int array[], const int end, const int max, const int min) {
  int i;
  const int range = max-min+1;
  int count[range+1],
      scratch[end];

  for(i=0; i<range+1; i++)
    count[i] = 0;

  /* Set the value of count[i] to the number of
   * elements in array with value i+min-1. */
  for(i=0; i<end; i++) {
    int c = array[i]-1-min;
    count[c]++;
  }

  /* Update count[i] to be the number of
   * elements with value less than i+min. */
  for(i=1; i<range; i++)
    count[i] += count[i-1];

  /* Copy the elements of array into scratch in
   * stable sorted order. */
  for(i=(end-1); i>=0; i--) {
    int c = array[i]-min;
    int s = count[c];
    scratch[s] = array[i];
    /* Increment count so that the next element
     * with the same value as the current element
     * is placed into its own position in scratch. */
    count[c]++;
  }

  for(i=0; i<end; i++)
    array[i] = scratch[i];
}

/**
 * return the appropriate percentile
 */
int getPercentile(double percent, int *array, int array_size) {
  int number = (floor(percent*array_size)+1); //-1 for arrays

  //Make number suitable for arrays
  number -= 1;

  //printf("%d\n", number);

  //Ensure the numbers aren't the same
  while(array[number-1]==array[number]) {
    number++;

    if(number>=array_size)
      return -1;
  }

  //printf("%d\n", number);

  return (int) array[number];
}

/**
 * The main method
 * part2 1000 datafile
 */ 
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  //I need three args
  //1 rows
  //2 file name
  if(argc==3) {
    int rows = 0;     
    if(sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &rows) == 0) {
      printf("The number of rows must be a number.\n");
      usage();   
      exit(-1);       
    }

    FILE *inputPtr; //File pointers
    inputPtr = fopen(argv[2], "r"); //same as PHP ;-)

    // Sensible errors
    if(inputPtr==NULL) {
      printf("I could not open the file for input.\n");
      usage();
      exit(-1);
    }

    // Read all the numbers
    int *numbers = (int *) calloc(rows, sizeof(int));

    int i = 0;
    int max = -1; //min
    int min = 500000000; //max
    while(fscanf(inputPtr, "%d", &numbers[i]) != EOF) {
      //printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
      if(numbers[i]>max) max = (int) numbers[i];
      if(numbers[i]<min) min = (int) numbers[i];
      i++;
    }

    printf("%d, %d, %d\n\n", min, max, rows);

    //int array[], const int end, const int max, const int min) {
    countingSort(numbers, rows, max, min);

    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      printf("%i: %d\n", i, numbers[i]);
    }  
    printf("-------\n\n");

    // Close the files
    //fclose(inputPtr);
    //not pointing to file anymore

    int percentile = getPercentile(0.9, numbers, rows);

    printf("%s: %d\n", argv[2], percentile);

  } else {
    printf("Please provide two CLI's!\n");
    usage();
    return 0;
  }


  /* All done */
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through a minimal test case (i.e. an input file with, say, 2 values which are or are not duplicates)?

Comment: I have tried and that segfaults as there is no concept of min/max if they are all equal!

Comment: OK, so a different minimal test case then, one that shows the problem you are seeing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a mistake:

```
/* Set the value of count[i] to the number of
 * elements in array with value i+min-1. */
for(i=0; i<end; i++) {
    int c = array[i]-1-min;
    count[c]++;
}
```

If the comment is correct, you ought to be setting `c = array[i]+1-min;`. Nothing else jumped out.

Comment: Solved the problem and I updated the wiki page I referenced this from! <3